# Does constexpr really imply const?

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, constexpr, static-members

Compare the following:

I have a static member in a class that is either `const constexpr` or just `constexpr`. According to this explanation on [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constexpr-cpp?view=msvc-170) constexpr implies constness:

> All constexpr variables are const.

However, this issues a warning in gcc 8.4:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct some_struct
{
    static constexpr char* TAG = "hello";
    void member() {
        printf("printing the tag %s", TAG);
    }  
};

int main()
{
    some_struct A;
    A.member();
}
```

While this doesn't:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct some_struct
{
    static const constexpr char* TAG = "hello";
    void member() {
        printf("printing the tag %s", TAG);
    }  
};

int main()
{
    some_struct A;
    A.member();
}
```

[Try it in CompilerExplorer.](https://godbolt.org/z/KjW9Pv5K1)

What is the difference?

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicate: The order of `const` and `constexpr` (and `static` and `char` for that matter) doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: `const char*` <- this variable is not const

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does constexpr really imply const?

Yes. Constexpr variables are always const.

> What is the difference?

`const T*` is a non-const pointer to const. It is not const.

`T* const` is a const pointer to non-const. It is const.

`const T* const` is a const pointer to const. It is const.

`constexpr T*` is a const pointer to non-const. It is const by virtue of being constexpr.

`const constexpr T*` is a const pointer to const. It is const by virtue of being constexpr.

String literals are arrays of const char, and they don't implicitly convert to a pointer to non-const char (since C++11).